# Bootstrap's Jquery and generally my css files not getting imported into html using Flask

Tags: jquery, css, flask

I tried linking css and jquery files to my code with many ways like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/design.css'">
   <link rel="stylesheet"href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cookieconsent@3/build/cookieconsent.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The code sometimes works, e.g when i copy a card from bootstrap into my html file, it displays fine and my navbar that requires css and jquery works fine. 
However, when try to use something that requires popper.js or bootstrap-select or even simply copy a dropdown-menu from bootstrap 
e.g.

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
  <form class="px-4 py-3">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleDropdownFormEmail1">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormEmail1" placeholder="email@example.com">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleDropdownFormPassword1">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleDropdownFormPassword1" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="dropdownCheck">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="dropdownCheck">
          Remember me
        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
  </form>
  <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New around here? Sign up</a>
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Forgot password?</a>
</div>
```

Literally nothing appears??
Could someone explain what is happening and how to fix it? I even tried using the downloaded files instead of the cdn, but still nothing.

Comment: Also forgot to add that none of my own css styles work when applied to an html element i.e. image, text even though i link to it first,and yes, my file paths are correct, i used the url_for static as a template variable (using jinja2 btw) and it displays the correct  file path

Comment: Have you tried the network tab in the chrome/firefox dev tools to make sure all resources *are* actually loading, and there's no errors in the console?  Also in your question, I notice that you don't load `bootstrap-select.min.js` after `bootstrap.min.js`.  Possibly need to include this specifically from a CDN.

Comment: Have you tried using `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` over CDN in favour of the Popper library? This bundle includes the necessary third party libraries.

Comment: I included all bootstrap files and still got nothing. Also tried using bundle.min.js. there were errors in the console, but the sources of errors had nothing to do with the main problem. fixed all errors and even tried starting a new flask app. This problem seems to only appear when I'm using flask, since I've never had this problem before. I've abandoned the project now. Will probably try using Django next time.